# jQuery GET Data from a select-option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, httprequest

I would like to send GET-Data from a Form-SELECT to a PHP-Script. 
Actually I've the following parts:

```
$.myload = function(query) {
$("#output").load("my_php_script.php");
}
```

The HTML:

```
 <form id="foo" method="post" name="bar">
 <select name="xxx">
 <option value="1" onclick="$.myload();">1</option>
 <option value="2" onclick="$.myload();">2</option>
 <option value="3" onclick="$.myload();">3</option>
 </select>
 </form>
 <!-- Something Else -->
 <div id="output">
 <!-- Paste Content from my_php_script.php -->
 </div>
```

The PHP (my_php_script.php):

```
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

That works fine for me. By clicking an option the Content "Hello World" is shown in the "output-DIV".
Now I want to send the value of the clicked/selected Option field. Example: A click on the first option should load the content of the script "my_php_script.php?value=1".
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your option like this -

```
<option value="1" onclick="$.myload(this);">1</option>
```

and in your function-

```
$.myload = function(query) {
  $("#output").load("my_php_script.php?value="+query.value);
}
```

**Edit :** Another approach -

Remove onclick attribute from your option's

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Change your query like this -

```
$.myload = function () {
    $("#output").load("my_php_script.php?value=" + this.value);
}
$('select[name=xxx]').on('change', $.myload);
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/4xt4j/

Answer (score 3):

You can use on your first $.myload parameter (with an onclick, the first parameter is the onclick event), and get data from event.currentTarget.value